# SVN - adding files that should be ignored

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've copied some new files into a subfolder in my repo. When I click Add in Tortoise SVN, I can see some files that shouldn't be added, I need to ignore them. I can also see it is ignoring lots of other files correctly.

So I alter the top-level `svn:global-ignores` adding `TestResults` to ignore that folder. I cannot commit this property change, since TortoiseSVN sees nothing to commit, so I assume property changes just happen directly, don't need committing.

Going back to add the files, I see them still listed. Why are some of my ignore patterns working and the new pattern is not?

Comment: Have you applied this recursively?

Comment: The `svn:global-ignores` is recursive as a feature in 1.8. Its working because binaries are not showing in the Add dialog, but the new pattern added to the bottom isn't working.

Comment: You can only have one `svn:global-ignores` entry, if you have two the second one will be ignored as far as I remember.

Comment: There's only one, but I updated it adding `TestResults`, because the code I've just copied into the repo from a POC/Spike has some tests. But the new pattern doesn't seem to apply, even though other patterns work.

Comment: Do I have to manually untick all the items I want ignored when adding stuff or should the ignore pattern work? It's odd.

Comment: You should not see any ignored items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the active global ignores with the following command:

```
svn pg svn:global-ignores /path/ -v --show-inherited-props
```

Comment: Thanks, `svn: E200005: 'C:\DATA\SVN\Blah\New-Folder-Blah' is not under version control` - this is where its odd to me, how can the ignore work on folders than aren't in SVN?

Comment: Maybe just your subfolder is not yet added? Or you could try a cleanup with `svn cleanup`

Comment: Well this is it, I haven't added it because its showing stuff in the Add list I thought would be ignored. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I have to use the Tortoise Add UI to remove the stuff I don't want added and then add it all.

Then it sees the folders that should be ignored. Very weird design.